Jenkins Could not find credentials matching aws credential when I push my image
I use jenkins pipeline to build and push image to my aws registry. I created a related credential, and its type is AWS credential named 'aws_credential'. But I got error message ERROR: Could not find credentials matching aws_credential. My pipeline is
        script.docker.withRegistry(registryUrl, registryCredentialsId) {
            def image = script.docker.image(imageName)
            image.push()
        }

The registryCredentialsId is 'aws_credential' and registryUrl is my aws registery url.
It read my credential and login successfully.

Ok, I make a mistake that I even havent install Amazon ECR plugin.
